# Remove template row in JXLS when input list is empty

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using JXLS to populate a template excel spreadsheet.  Sometimes, one input - a list - is empty.  When this happens, the template fields which use this list are shown in the populated spreadsheet in full JXLS regalia - eg, "`${someList.someValue}`".

The fields in question are all in a single row (expanded to `list.size()` rows by JXLS).  I want to clear the whole row when there are no records in the list.

Is there a way to do so in JXLS?  Alternatively, can anyone suggest a complementary way to use JExcel or POI to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <jx:if> tags in your excel template.
For example if you have a template similar to the following

```
Row 1: <jx:if test="${!empty someData}">
Row 2: place holders for data that will be printed in the loop 
Row 3: </jx:if>
```

If someData is not empty then rows will be printed in the output but if someData is empty then no rows will be printed by this template.

I hope I could make it clear. Please see http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/tags.html for more information about tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've tried using tags but the parser throws an exception reading the '/' character in the closing tag.  The tag cells in my template looks similar to the example on the JXLS site, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you post your template code. It looks like a syntax error.

Comment: My template uses the same tags as shown in your example, except obviously my test is different.  The exception is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set formula: / at net.sf.jxls.formula.FormulaControllerImpl.writeFormulas(FormulaControllerImpl.java:137)...Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 0 '/' in specified formula '/'. Expected cell ref or constant literal

Comment: Can that error be caused by a slash character at another cell? I don't think that jx:if tag will be parsed into a formula. Exception message states the '/' is at character 0 of the formula.

Comment: I agree the message seems to indicate that, but the template works fine without the tags.  If I remove the closing </jx:if> tag the exception doesn't occur but no parameter replacement occurs.

Comment: Can you check the opening jx:if tag, especially the test attribute, for a syntax error. Unfortunately that's all I can suggest at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible via POI - perhaps even POI object interface of JXLS:

From http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html:
*Modifying the file you have read in is simple. You retrieve the object via an assessor method, remove it via a parent object's remove method (sheet.removeRow(hssfrow)) and create objects just as you would if creating a new xls. When you are done modifying cells just call workbook.write(outputstream) just as you did above.*

From http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/customprocessor.html:
*With Row object you have access to related POI objects to modify cell style if required.*

Comment: Thanks for your response Yahia; I've accepted Serkan's answer as it makes better use of JXLS features and keeps the logic in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason the rows do not display based on the jx:if condition is if there is some space before the jx:if tag